# Mounting exterior shutters on deeply recessed windows

Tags: insulation, hinges, shutters

I want to mount shutters on my 1930's house, but since we've had it insulated with polystyrene, the recess is 7 inches. That would need a huge offset hinge!! The windows are metal-cased woodframed double glazing. I would like the shutters to look authentic, and don't want to mount them outside the window. We would use Fischer Thermax wal plugs for the outside mount, but my concern is the window frame, and getting hold of such long shutter hinges.

Comment: This all depends on where you want the shutters to be when open and closed. Can you draw a top-down picture of that?

Comment: Photos would be invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the open shutters to run parallel to the wall, some kind of offset hinge is needed. But creating such a hinge to mount the shutters shouldn't be too hard.

[image: shutter hinge]

The pivot point needs to be slightly outward of the midpoint of the well around the window. The lower tail of the hinge in the image can be cut off, or it can be bent to fit against the window casing.

You should be able to find standard flat strap hinges that can be bent and cut to suit. A bench vise would be the easiest way to make the bends.

Because there is such a long reach, you may want three hinges per shutter.

Answer (score 0):

"Authentic" shutters on thick walls (think stone) are typically on the outside face of the wall, not close to the window inside the recess.

"Shutter stone wall" will search you a bunch of images, too many of which have copyright issues for me to sort through them and find a good one that does not.